# Is order of decorators important while using Decorator Design Pattern in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

While reading about use of Java I/O classes I've seen multiple variants of many objects used to get another result and I wonder if is it important to put these objects in specific order or I just have to use them no matter in what order.

For example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME)))
```

Does it matter if BufferedReader "wraps" FileReader and not vice versa? Would the code work the same way when it were written that way:

```
new FileReader(new BufferedReader(FILENAME))
```

I dont't say only about the situation when there are just two objects used, does the order of "wrappers" matter when we use even more of them?

Comment: As it stands, It's a bit unclear what exactly are you asking. Please explain with a few code examples before the question is downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I hope I made it clear right now.

Comment: Well, both your code examples are the same! Both cases wrap a `FileReader` in a `BufferedReader`. At this point, I highly recommend that you gather your thoughts and think about what you are asking. The answer is already there.

Comment: Second code doesn't compile.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you just confirm it to me to make it clear - wrappers used in many various cases and situations must be used in strictly defined order. I'm asking because there are so many classes in I/O library and it seems a bit difficult to me to use them correctly as I'm still a Java newbie. Sorry if my question was not proper.

Comment: @slavvv1011 It totally depends on what class you are using. There is no hard and fast rule that all decorator pattern implementations will only allow one way wrapping. I could create two classes A and B where A has a constructor that takes B and B has a constructor that takes A which will allow me to wrap A into B and B into A. Clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a BufferedReader constructor expect a FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340922/what-does-a-bufferedreader-constructor-expect-a-filereader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it matter if BufferedReader "wraps" FileReader and not vice
>   versa? Would the code work the same way when it were written that way:
>
> ```
> new FileReader(new BufferedReader(FILENAME))
> ```

Yes, it does. A `FileReader` reads, as the name suggests, files, a `BufferedReader` does not, so passing a filename to `BufferedReader` doesn't make sense, and doesn't compile.

`FileReader`, on the other hand, *only* reads files. It makes no sense to pass other streams to it, as it was made to read files, not other streams, so passing `BufferedReader` to it doesn't compile.

Now, there might be instances where the order doesn't matter, in this case however, it does.

Note though, `FileReader` is not a decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is not the same. Just consider that as a chain.

Simple example: when read() is called on a buffered reader bound to a File IO (through given FileReader) it parameterizes a read() on the underlying FileReader's file and then feeds (in turn) its own buffer based on the return bytes which is then returned to the caller. So you are actually doing buffered file reading.

You cannot simply do the reverse: read() called on FileReader that triggers or is bound to a buffered read() on a BufferedReader ?? -> makes no sense (what will the latest actually read?)

You should review the basics of streams in Java for completeness.